# Ubuntu sound settings gone

Tags: 14.04, sound, settings

Ubuntu froze and I was forced to shut it down with brute force (holding the power button). Ever since then the sound settings have disappeared and I am not able to adjust the volume / select the output and etc. There is sound, the only thing missing is the settings for it.
Here is a pic:

[image]

(Linux Ubuntu 14.04 with GNOME desktop environment)

Comment: try this: `killall pulseaudio -KILL` and then `pulseaudio -D`

Comment: There was no process pulseaudio and the second 'Daemon startup failed'

Comment: Which GNOME version?

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm not aware of the version of Gnome. Although I don't believe it's related to the problem I'm having. Same problem occurs while using the Unix Desktop Environment.

Answer (score 2):

Try running the following command and then, reboot:

```
rm -r ~/.config/pulse; pulseaudio -k
```

[Click here for more info.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio#Resetting_User_Configuration)

Answer (score 0):

With me the problem was with `pulseaudio-equalizer`. After I removed the eponymous package all devices were back instantly. I suggest you try it.

Comment: I doubt your issue was actually caused by `pulseaudio-equalizer`. However, (un-)installing that packages changes the PulseAudio configuration and restarts the PA daemon (see the other answer). This was likely what fixed the issue.